# How to select a list of fields within a struct by prefix using Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT
  STRUCT(
    c.customer.name*,
    r.revenue.type*
  ) AS customer_revenue
FROM customer_table c
JOIN revenue_table r
USING (transaction_id)
```

Where `customer` is a struct containing a number of fields, including some that begin with "name" (and some fields that don't), and `revenue` is similarly a struct, with some fields that begin with "type" and some fields that don't.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this in BigQuery. I just keep getting syntax errors that lead me to believe it's not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: not doable really :o( you might need to rethink your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below alternative way

```
#standardSQL
SELECT (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(x) 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(c.customer), '{}'), r'("name\w+":\w+)(?:,|$)')) x
  ) || ',' || (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(y) 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(r.revenue), '{}'), r'("type\w+":\w+)(?:,|$)')) y
  ) AS customer_revenue
FROM customer_table c
JOIN revenue_table r
USING (transaction_id)
```

in case of below [super simplified] data

```
#standardSQL
WITH customer_table AS (
  SELECT 1 transaction_id, STRUCT(1 AS name1, 2 AS name2, 3 AS aaa3, 4 AS bbb4) customer
), revenue_table AS (
  SELECT 1 transaction_id, STRUCT(11 AS type11, 22 AS type22, 33 AS type33, 44 AS ccc44) revenue
)
```

result will be

```
Row customer_revenue     
1   "name1":1,"name2":2,"type11":11,"type22":22,"type33":33
```

Obviously - thi sis not exactly what you ask in your question - but as I already commented - "not doable really :o( you might need to rethink your requirements" - so above solution can potentially help you in doing this

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty clunky but does seem like the only way to do this. I appreciate the effort!